# Next JS/ Vercel severe performance issues

Tags: javascript, performance, next.js, vercel

#### Dear Community,

Just some time ago, my still simple next.js application has started experiencing extremely severe performance issues (on api calls? or maybe in general) --> but only on desktop.

[image]

This is the waterfall for one of the page loads. each submission endpoint here is simply going to a next.js api route, authenticating with auth0 and then fetching some minor data on neondb using the prisma ORM.

[image]

This is another one where the "me" endpoint (also an endpoint on the same Next deployment needed for auth0) also takes a while.

As I already mentioned, opening the page on the phone, at least my android phone, is as snappy and fast as it should be with only a fraction of a second for each load

=> My guess is that this is somehow vercel, spinning up multiple serverless functions for each call, meaning that the time is caused by the cold start delay (see the runtime of `35.16s/35.35s/35.17s/16.86s: an outlier` for the submission calls), but I have no idea how to control that and would also like some more perspectives on the issue...
I also want to rule out net work issues, since other websites are working fine and i dont believe the issue is from auth0s response time, since local development environments of the project are also loading as quickly as expected...

#### Here is some code for the implementation:

Client side (app/submissions/page.tsx):

```
"use client";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "@/src/redux/hooks";
import { addSubmission, setSubmissions } from "@/src/redux/slices/songProcessSlice";
import { submissionType } from "@/src/types/submissionTypes";
import { withPageAuthRequired } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

async function saveSubmission(submission: submissionType) {
  const response = await fetch("/api/submissions", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(submission)
  })
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response.statusText)
  }
  return await response.json();
}

async function getSubmissions() {
  const response = await fetch("/api/submissions", {
    method: "GET",
  })
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response.statusText)
  }
  return await response.json();
}

export default withPageAuthRequired(function Submissions() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [submissionForm, setSubmissionForm] = useState<submissionType>({
    artistName: "",
    artistEmail: "",
    songName: "",
    songUrl: "",
    socialUrl: "",
  })
  const submissions = useAppSelector(state => state.songProcessReducer.submissions)

  useEffect(() => {
    getSubmissions().then(resp => {
      console.log(resp)
      dispatch(setSubmissions(resp))
    })
  }, [])

  const handleFormChange = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setSubmissionForm(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  
  }

  const handleFormClick = () => {

    try {
      let isFormEmpty = false
      Object.keys(submissionForm).forEach((key) => {
        if (submissionForm[key as keyof submissionType] === "") {
          isFormEmpty = true;
        }
      })
      if (!isFormEmpty) {
        const date = new Date();
        const tempSubmissionForm: submissionType = {
          ...submissionForm,
          creationTime: date.toUTCString()
        }
        saveSubmission(tempSubmissionForm).then(resp => {
          console.log(resp)
          dispatch(addSubmission(resp))
          setSubmissionForm({
            artistName: "",
            artistEmail: "",
            songName: "",
            songUrl: "",
            socialUrl: "",
          })
        })
      }
      else {
        alert("Please fill out all fields to add the submission")
      }
      
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error("error", e)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="mb-4 text-lg font-bold">Submissions</div>
      <div className="mb-2">Add Submission</div>
      <div className="grid gap-4 grid-cols-2 grid-rows-3 mb-4">
        <div className="w-full">
...
...
```

Server APIs (app/api/submissions/route.ts):

```
import { getAccessToken, withApiAuthRequired } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const POST = withApiAuthRequired(async (req: Request) => {
  try {
    const submissionData = await req.json()
    const savedSubmission = await prisma.submission.create({
      data: submissionData
    })
    return NextResponse.json(savedSubmission, {status: 201});
  }
  catch (e: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: "There hast been an Error!", message: e.message}, {status: 500})
  }
});

const GET = withApiAuthRequired(async (req: Request) => {
  try {
    const submission = await prisma.submission.findMany();
    return NextResponse.json(submission, {status: 200});
  }
  catch (e: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: "There hast been an Error!", message: e.message}, {status: 500})
  }
});

export {
  POST,
  GET
}
```

Comment: You cannot control cold start, as its a side effect of using serverless. If you have an idea when your api calls will happen, you can "warm" the lambdas before those calls.

Comment: But 30s seems like too much (even for serverless). Try profiling/logging with your lambda to see whats taking this much time.

Comment: @RobinThomas thats true... it has to be something system specific too... otherwise, why would it run well on my phone but not on any Windows browser - I really don't see any other connection

Comment: I could try adding some logging to my endpoints so I can timestamp the excact point where the delay is happening, that might be worth a shot, what do you think?

Comment: Just checked the logs, vercel actually tracks and logs api requests by itself, but its hard to get any knowledge from it, since every hit is (expectedly) as far apart as the loading suggests...

Comment: Here you can see the time stamps from the mobile traffic, only 1 to 2 seconds apart as they should be clicking throught the app and authenticating/ fetching data https://ibb.co/TMTH9R8. https://ibb.co/N1k5b4M
this one the fastest i can go on the pc